# Turn 0 bits to 1 bits if the bit is between low and high

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Full disclosure, this is a homework problem and I do not need exact code. I am tasked with reproducing the following code while only using ~ & + <<.

```
int result = 0;
int i;
for(i = lowbit; i <= highbit; i++)
    result |= 1 << i;
return result;
```

Where `lowbit` and `highbit` are parameters between `0` and `31` inclusive. If `lowbit` is a larger number than `highbit`, return 0.

What I have tried so for is the following code

```
int result = 0;
int negone = ~0x0;
int first = 1 << (lowbit + negone); //the first 1 bit is at the lowbit th location
int last = 1 << (highbit + negone); //the last 1 bit is at the highbit th location
int tick = ~(first + last); //attempting to get all bits in the range of low and highbit.
result = ~(~first & ~tick); //bitwise | without using |
result = ~(~last & ~result);
return result + 1; //the first bit should always be on.
```

So is there something fundamental I am missing here? In addition to what I have not working this also goes over my limit of 12 operators that I am allowed to use, but I'd like to try and get it working before I even begin to limit the operators.

When I run the test script on this I get errors on most of the tests it is put against including `lowbit` and `highbit` being equal to each other. Cases where `highbit` is the max size and `lowbit` is the least size seem to work though.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So would I need to make allones unsigned so that it used logical right shift in order to 0 out the bits on the left of my highbit? Thank you very much for the help that does make a lot of sense.

Comment: Are your teachers forcing you to also use signed integers?

Comment: @2501 no I can define local variables as I see fit.

Comment: You have also used the assignment `=` operator and the parentheses `(...)` not listed in the "allowed operators".  Are they also allowed?

Comment: @Clifford yes as () is not an operator and does not change bit patterns and as = only stores values into a register they are both not restricted. Although the marked answer does make a clear and concise answer that does not use = at all if the final result value is just returned rather than assigning it to a variable and then returning its value.

Comment: In C `(...)` is certainly an operator (singular).  See the operator table http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`negone` should be initialized this way:

```
uint32_t negone = ~0UL;
```

You are adding the bit number with a bit pattern in:

```
int first = 1 << (lowbit + negone); //the first 1 bit is at the lowbit th location
int last = 1 << (highbit + negone);
```

You should instead compute the 32 bit masks

```
uint32_t first = negone << lowbit;  // all bits below lowbit are 0, others are 1
uint32_t last = negone << highbit << 1;  // all bits above highbit are 1, other are 0
```

The result is obtained by masking the complement of `first` with `last`:

```
uint32_t result = ~first & last;
```

Combining the above steps gives is a direct solution with 7 operators (12 including the parentheses and the assignment), no addition, and no subtraction:

```
uint32_t result = ~(~0UL << highbit << 1) & (~0UL << lowbit);
```

I use `0UL` because type `unsigned long` is guaranteed to have at least 32 bits, whereas type `unsigned int` might have just 16 bits.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a problem that it does not take into account if lowbit and highbit are 0, in which case the right most bit should be 1.

Comment: @KurtPrice: I fixed the answer to include `highbit`.

Comment: Ah I see that is a really ingenious way of doing it. So first we take all bits 1 with the ~0ULL giving us an unsigned long long type with all 1 bits, then we shift that over highbit + 1 times. This should then give us the ~ of the bits from 0 to highbit that must be 1? Then we do the same shift with lowbit anding them together to get the overlap?

Comment: @KurtPrice: Exactly. And type `unsigned long` is actually sufficient for this computation.

Comment: The original code sets the bits low to high to 1 and leaves other bits unchanged rather then zero.  It is true however that the original initialises `result` to zero so it is in fact the same thing, but it is not clear that that is intended since it would otherwise also use simple assignment.rather then `|=`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a mask with the bits low to high set:

```
uint32_t mask = ~(~0ul << highbit << 1) & (~0ul << lowbit)
```

Example:  lowbit = 4, highbit = 12 (9 bits)

```
mask = ~(0xffffffff << 12 << 1) & (0xffffffff << 4)
     = ~(0xffff7000) & 0xfffffff0
     =   0x00001fff  & 0xfffffff0
     =   0x00001ff0
```

2) Apply the mask to the value to be modified, this most simply an `|` operation, but that is not a valid operator in this exercise, so must be transformed using De Morgan's forum:

`A|B` -> `~(~A & ~B)` :

```
result = ~(~result & ~mask) ;
```

It is of course possible to combining the two steps, but perhaps clarity would not then be served.

Comment: You're not allowed to use the `-` operator.

Comment: Thank you this will help a lot, but for the question I am not allowed to use | I have to replace it with the ~ and & equivalent. You may want to change that for future viewers.

Comment: And you're not allowed to use the `>>` operator.

Comment: Simplified and fixed.

Comment: Note that step 1 is equivalent to @chqrlie's *final* solution - credit is due, although I did derive it independently if not so qhickly.

Comment: Actually your step 1 has a flaw: `~0u << (highbit+1)` is implementation defined for 32-bit `unsigned int` and `highbit == 31`.  You can avoid this by writing: `~0u << highbit << 1` and you can make it portable to environments with smaller `int` sizes by using an `unsigned long` literal: `~0UL << highbit << 1`.

Comment: @chqrlie @ Good point;  I was trying to make the *arithmetic* clear (and avoiding a verbatim copy of your solution!). I doubt that the *actual* behaviour of any reasonable compiler would cause a problem, but it would be unwise to knowingly invoke undefined behaviour.  Fixed.  Interestingly perhaps, the solution does not require the allowed `+` operator, so one wonders whether the author of the assignment understands this.

Comment: @Clifford: indeed! but the authors might have been thinking of `~0ULL << (highbit + 1)`, which is OK too.

Comment: @chqrlie :  True, but given the use of plain `int` it would appear that such careful  attention to type has not been taught, so I doubt it somehow.

Comment: @Clifford: You are correct! The original code posted (presumably copied from the instructor's question) is incorrect as it computes `1 << i` with `i` potentially iterating to `31`.  I agree with you, the instructor overlooked the subtle issues regarding shifting and signed types.

Answer (score 0):

The original code generates a block of `1` from `lowbit` on until `highbit` (inclusive).
This can be achieved without a loop as follows:

```
int nrOfBits = highbit + ~lowbit + 2;  // highbit - lowbit + 1
int shift = (nrOfBits & 0x1f + 1);
int result = ~(~(1 << shift)+1) << lowbit;
```

The idea is that, for example a range of 8 bits filled up with `1` means a number of `255`, whereas `2^8` is `256`. So - as operator `-` is not allowed, we use 2-complement to get `-256`, add `1` to get `-255`, and turn it back to `+255` using 2-complement operator `~`. Then, we just have to shift the block `lowbits` left.

Comment: The `-` operator can be transformed to `+` by creating teh two's complement of the right operand:  `nrOfBits = highbit + (~lowbit +1) + 1` which simplified to `nrOfBits = highbit + ~lowbit + 2`.

Comment: `~` generates the one's-complement rather than two's-complement.  It is the expression `~lowbit + 1` that is the two's complement of `lowbit`. That is `~lowbit + 1` == `-lowbit`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be that `tick = ~(first+last)` does not flip the bit from the lowbit to the highbit.

Maybe we can do something like this:

```
/* supposed that lowbit = 1, highbit = 2 */
uint32_t negone = ~(0u); /* negone = all 1s */
uint32_t first = negone << lowbit;  /* first = ...111110 */
uint32_t last = (1 << (highbit + 1)) + negone; /* last = ...0000111 */
uint32_t tick = last & first; /* tick = ...000110 */
result = ~(~result&~tick); /* Bitwise Or without | as you mentioned. */
```

It takes 11 bit operations to do this.

p.s. I am wondering why the first bit should be always on.

Edit: In order to avoid undefined operation, we should use unsigned type, like `uint32_t`.

Comment: in the loop that they show if lowbit is 0 and highbit is 0, then the loop will see it as 0 <= 0 and run once. This then means we do result |= 1 << 0;

Comment: `negone << lowbit` is undefined behavior.